# levels in R Programming

Tags: r

I am self teaching R for few weeks now. I came across some problem I don't understand. So if I say

```
fert <- as.factor(c(50,20,10,10,20,50))
levels(fert)
```

I get

```
[1] "10" "20" "50"
```

I get until this point. What I don't get is if I say

```
levels(fert)[fert]
```

I get

```
"50" "20" "10" "10" "20" "50"
```

which is the definition of `fert`. I don't understand what the logic is with this `[fert]`thing.

Comment: @Pascal I preemptively edited his question to what I believe he was actually doing when he saw the output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a `factor` i'm presuming, so:

```
fert <-  factor(c(50,20,10,10,20,50))
levels(fert)
#[1] "10" "20" "50"
```

Factors are stored as sequential numbers with labels, like:

```
as.numeric(fert)
#[1] 3  2  1  1  2  3
#  corresponding to the labels of:
#   50 20 10 10 20 50
```

So, since:

```
levels(fert)[c(3,2,1,1,2,3)]
#[1] "50" "20" "10" "10" "20" "50"
```

then,

```
levels(fert)[fert]
#[1] "50" "20" "10" "10" "20" "50"
```